# How to use code which runs in browser and outside browser together (node.js filesystem)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to enter path to the folder in browser and display all file names which located inside, i found that it will possible with node fs, but i also have code which runs at browser, and it need vars, located in file, which will run outside of the browser with node. I need to create server with node and runs all code from it?  Or what you can reccomend me to reach this goal? PS: By the way i use webpack

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between javascript in browser end and server end. You can't access the directory directly from the browser. You need some sort of backend technology like PHP, Java, node, python, etc in order to get the file list. You can use node server and below code for the reading directory. Then make a simple HTTP request to your backend server from the frontend.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

app.get('/getfiles',  async (req, res) => {
  const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
    let data = [];
    await fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
        //handling error
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        } 
        
        //listing all files using forEach
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            // Do whatever you want to do with the file
            data.push(file)
        });
    });
    
    res.send(data);

});



app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) By the way, i can't read directory, if node will not installed localy on the PC where my site runs? Or it all will be on server, sorry i'm not backend :)

Comment: node server will run on localhost:3000 port and your web server  web server will run on localhost:80 in generally

Comment: so..yea? I just want to use it in different PC's, in which node is not installed. I will found more about it

Comment: you don't need a different pc you need different server

Comment: I mean that i will host it, and another people can use it, so i asking it, if app will work, and gets access to their files, on certain PC

Comment: only in your backend (server) pc